# Print out all the ancestor node names for a given node in a tree in java?

Tags: java, recursion, tree

In a company, there is one CEO and a hierarchy of managers and employees below him, given an employee at the lowest level of the hierarchy print out the names of all his higher ups all the way to the ceo. How to implement this in Java?

Answer (score 0):

as you don't give us nothing of code, thats the best we can give you as general idea in pseudocode:

```
function String drawHierarchy(Employee employee){
    print "Employee name {}" + employee.getName();
    if(employee.getParent() != null){
        return drawHierarchy(employee.getParent());  
    } 
}
```